# Extracting class element

Tags: extract, element

Tried "title = soup.find(class_=' _6YOLH _1JtW7 _2VF_A _2OMMP').get_text().strip()" to extract the title but keep getting attribute error that nonetype object has no attribute. Code is below. Any help is appreciated.

Classic Fit Solid Wool Suit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if the attribute exists first then try to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked. It does exist. Here's the websites element inside of an h1 tag:

itemprop="name" overrideelementwith="div" class=" _6YOLH _1JtW7 _2VF_A _2OMMP">Classic Fit Solid Wool Suit